# Send request parameter from console commands laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, guzzle

How can I send request via console commands in laravel 5.1 ? I need to pass API request to controller in same folder project, my first attempt is using guzzle :

```
$gClient =  new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => env('URL_AUTO_CONFIRM_PAYMENT')]);

$res = $gClient->post('api/payment/inquiries',
                            [
                                'headers'=> [
                                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                                ],
                                'json'=>[
                                    'payment_method' => 'transfer',
                                    'payment_channel' => 'bca',
                                    'account_number' => $row->parameter['accountNo'],
                                    'invoice_id' => $row->parameter['paymentInvoice'],
                                    'amount' => (int)$row->parameter['totalCommission'],
                                    'currency_code' => 'IDR',
                                    'description' => 'Testing'
                                ],
                                'http_errors' => false
                            ]
                    );
```

but I think its not good because in same folder project, which can I call controller directly, but the problem is, my controller has been set to only receive $request not param (my_controller(Request $request)).
So, how can I handle this ? It is ok using guzzle ? Or should I use another alternative ?
Any advice will appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a [request instance](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v4.0.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L233) and pass that to the specific controller method.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$request = new Request(
  [
    'payment_method' => 'transfer',
    'payment_channel' => 'bca',
    'account_number' => $row->parameter['accountNo'],
    'invoice_id' => $row->parameter['paymentInvoice'],
    'amount' => (int)$row->parameter['totalCommission'],
    'currency_code' => 'IDR',
    'description' => 'Testing'
  ],
  [],
  [], 
  [],
  [],
  ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json']
);

$response = $controller->edit($request);
```

Comment: its caused Undefined index: SERVER_NAME , it is caused $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in my controller.

Comment: Okk solved $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] on my own, and your answer is work like a charm